# from contours to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a contours finder program based on opencv, now I'm trying to get the number of corners in each founded contour using Harris corners detector, my problem is that I have to get one elements of the contours

```
............................
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
...........................
    for ( int i =0;i <contours.size(); i++){
            if(!contours[i].empty()){
                Harris.detect(cv::Mat(contours[i])); // here crashes the program because the dimensions don't fit ????
                Harris.getCorners(approx,0.4);
            std::cout <<"size \n"<< approx.size()<<std::endl; 
            }
        }
.........................
```

**UPDATE**

I checked the code again and the program crashed in this part of the Harris  class :

```
   void HarrisDetector::detect(const cv::Mat& image) {
        // Harris computation
        cv::cornerHarris(image,cornerStrength,  //  here crashs the program 
            neighbourhood,// neighborhood size
            aperture,     // aperture size
            k);           // Harris parameter

    // internal threshold computation
    double minStrength; // not used
    cv::minMaxLoc(cornerStrength,&minStrength,&maxStrength);
    //local maxima detection
    cv::Mat dilated;  // temporary image
    cv::dilate(cornerStrength,dilated,cv::Mat());
    cv::compare(cornerStrength,dilated,localMax,cv::CMP_EQ);
     }
```

any ideaa

Comment: The problem you have is that Harris Corners works on pictures not simply Mat! but making a Mat out of contours[i] you have an incomplete picture which causes the error.

Comment: @Khashayar  thanks for your comment, take a look at the update of the question.

Comment: As I said what you are doing to find the corners of a contour is not possible with cornerHarris! check here for a cornerHarris example http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html

Comment: tell me if what you want is finding contour corners because there is a better way!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method` argument in `cv::findContours` function to some approximation and then use the `contours[i].size()` to get a number of corners.

Comment: I already used the cv::findContours method to get the contours no I want to work with each vector of points in it, so each vector must be a cv::Mat type